# Can't show category products in home page

Tags: category, products, ce-1.9.2.1

I'm trying to show products from a specific category in home page.

I have inserted content into CMS > Pages > HP as follow

```
A 
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="28" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} 
B
```

Category 28 is anchor. Category 28 contains valid products. Cleared the cache many times.

When I reload the home page the result is:
AB

Comment: you're missing "name" in the block (tho not sure if that will fix your issue). also did you make sure the products in that category are assigned to the website of this homepage?

Comment: I trying adding the name as follow {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="28" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} still not working. 

Yes products in that category are assigned to the website of the home page

Comment: how about changing `column_count` to `products_count` or `max_shown`?

Comment: tried both and still not working. By the way, on top of catalog/product/list.phtml I'm printing some chars to be sure the phtml is called but it's not

Comment: Do I need to have something inside page_layout_update_xml ?

Comment: shouldn't need to.. I have that same setup in a static block.. have you got a block working before?

Comment: Yes, using the following code it show hp_boxes.phtml {{block type="hpboxes/hpboxes" name="hp_boxes.cms" template="homepage/hp_boxes.phtml" block_id="1"}}

Comment: I dunno then, I'm stumped :/.. maybe a bit far-reached but do you have catalog/product/list.phtml in your custom theme?

Comment: Yes I do. Apparently if I add the following code to page_layout_update_xml it shows the products in list.phtml <reference name="content"><block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"></block></reference> but it's missing the "compare" button and the "add to cart" button... but still not showing the block called this way {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="28" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}

Answer (score 2):

As said in [this recent thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94026/product-list-by-category-in-cms-page), in versions above 1.9.2.2 (or previous versions with all security patches applied) Magento requires permission to load specific widgets or blocks.

You gotta create this permission in **'System->Permissions->Blocks'** menu, as *catalog/product_list*

It worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the only way I found to show the category products in home page is to paste this code inside page_layout_update_xml

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>28</category_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Buttons "compare" and "add to cart" were only hidden

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your category (id 28) is under your root category, it should not be another root category otherwise its not displayed